# Using navigation in context actions throws the exception

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have problem with listview. There is command on VM that takes me to another page (navigation service is basically NavigationPage.PushAsync). There is no problem when i click 'add' on toolbar, but clicking on context actions throws the exception. It only happens on Android, iOS and WP works fine. I'm using Xamarin.Forms 1.5.0.6447. Is this Xamarin bug? Is there any workaround?

Code looks like this:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listView.ItemsSource = new List<string>() {"Item1", "Item2", "Item2"};
}

private void MenuItem_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
}
```

---

```
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="ActionToolbar" Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked"></ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

  <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Text="ActionContext" Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked"></MenuItem>
          </ViewCell.ContextActions>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

---

```
9-29 08:51:49.395 I/MonoDroid(  367): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): System.ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): Parameter name: jobject
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001f, 0x000c8>
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): at Android.Views.ActionModeInvoker.Finish () <IL 0x00038, 0x0013f>
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CellAdapter.OnActionItemClicked (Android.Views.ActionMode,Android.Views.IMenuItem) <IL 0x0001e, 0x00127>
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): at Android.Views.ActionMode/ICallbackInvoker.n_OnActionItemClicked_Landroid_view_ActionMode_Landroid_view_MenuItem_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001c, 0x00153>
09-29 08:51:49.400 I/MonoDroid(  367): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.a3e64c2b-1708-4b07-8091-f8943a9b230f (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001d, 0x00053>
09-29 08:51:49.410 W/art     (  367): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
```

Comment: Going to need a bit more code to try and resolve this. the binding on your MenuItem looks odd. It looks like your ListView is bound to a list of items where each item has a BindingContext set to something that contains an implementation of AddCommand.

Comment: @David It's not the issue. I simplified the code and added bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34517

Comment: Glad you got it isolated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
await Task.Yield();
```

before Navigation.PushAsync helped.